# Hyperlink in MySql Database

Tags: mysql, database, hyperlink

I have a MySql database online for transcriptions of document images.  Those images are located on another website.  I want to include the link to the actual image in the database so that the person researching can click the link and go directly to the image.
I have done the following:
    Created a column named IMAGE
    In my excel spreadsheet that will be uploaded via ODBC to PhpMyAdmin for my datbase, i have included the [IMAGE](http://%20%20plus%20the%20actual%20link%20)

When the file is uploaded via ODBC, I can see the link in the Table on PhpMyAdmin for my database.
I have also included the IMAGE column to be shown on my results page and the column does appear.

But the hyperlink does NOT appear at all on the results page for any entry that has a link in the Image column so there is nothing to click on to go directly to the image

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please post your code so we can take a look?

Comment: I have now found several articles telling me I can't do it from within the Sql database and that I need to insert the code in PHP but I do not understand how to code PHP.  The website was originally coded by someone who is no longer in business in 2010.  Can anyone help me to code the php to retrieve the link from mysql?

Comment: We would need a lot more information such as the database structure. Unfortunately, that is off-topic for Stack Overflow. SO exists to help you with existing code, not to write it for you. I suggest reading some documentation located [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) to try and get a better understanding of what you need to do.

Comment: <td align="right"><?php echo $item['NOTES']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['IMAGE']; ?></td>   </tr>

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up quickly to try and help you out. You will need to change DBHOST, DBUSERNAME, yourtablename etc to your databases information.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("DBHOST","DBUSERNAME","DBPASSWORD","DBNAME");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 'yourtablename'");    

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Notes</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['NOTES'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['IMAGE'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Edit: Here is an alternate solution that will put the link formatting in for you.

I wrote this up quickly to try and help you out. You will need to change DBHOST, DBUSERNAME, yourtablename etc to your databases information.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("DBHOST","DBUSERNAME","DBPASSWORD","DBNAME");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 'yourtablename'");    

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Notes</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['NOTES'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='" . $row['IMAGE'] . "'>Link</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't retrieve what is located in the table for IMAGE.  it looks like this in the sql table for an entry under the column IMAGE  <a href="http://dl.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/v/Archivio+di+Stato+di+Palermo/Stato+civile+della+restaurazione/Terminioggi+Termini+Imerese/Matrimoni+processetti/1820/109/007803563_01052.jpg.html">Image</a>  I want that to become clickable once it is retrieved.  Instead it brings forth and empty cell with nothing to click on

Comment: Is anything being printed for the "NOTES" section? Could you post errors you might have in your webserver error log?

Comment: Please check the edit I made. Try putting a normal link in the database (ex: https://www.google.com) instead of one with the href tags. The second set of code should add it automatically.

Comment: I really didn't think this was going to be such a problem to get done. The web page you sent me to was of no help with this either

Comment: yes there are notes in the notes column but they are NOT webpages.  They are information to assist the user in the transcription such as age at the time of death or who reported a death, etc.

Comment: After changing it to your code, I get the following in teh IMAGE column    . " . $row['IMAGE'] . " instead of the link to click on

Comment: made some progress.  Now it shows Image as a hyperlink in each row even when there isn't a link in that row for the Image column.  But the 3 that do have links return 404 errors when you click on them so now I have to figure out that part.  Also, now across the top of my table I have the following:  echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo "";

Comment: this the error message I am receiving    The requested URL /" . $item[ was not found on this server.  The url is correct 

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Could you add a reply to your question that shows the code you're using that partially works so I can take a look at it? I'll take a look when I'm done work.